# How to solve parametric quadratic function?

Tags: functions, quadratics, parametric

i have problem to solve following equation:

> Find $b$ and $c$ if the graph of the function $y = 2x ^ 2 + bx + c$ touches the axis $Ox$ at the point $(1; 0)$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This does not really seem to be a parametrization like $x(t)=...$ and $y(t)=...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = 2x ^ 2 + bx + c$ passes through the point $(1,0)$

$2+b+c=0\tag{1}$

Furthermore it is tangent to $x$-axis, so the solution $x=1$ must be double

Which means that the discriminant of $2x ^ 2 + bx + c=0$ is zero, that is

$b^2-8c=0\tag{2}$
From $(1)$ solve $c=-b-2$ and plug into $(2)$

$b^2-8(-b-2)=0\to (b+4)^2=0\to b=-4$ and $c=2$

Answer (score 1):

A quadratic that touches the $x$ axis when $x=1$ has the form $y=a(x-1)^2=ax^2-2ax+a.$

Equate the coefficients to those of $2x^2+bx+c$ to find $b$ and $c$.